# YFS201 Flow sensor frequency to voltage converter circuit reg

Tags: sensor, circuit-design, frequency

I am using YFS201 flow sensors to detect the flow of water in a pipe . 
 The response from the flow sensor is frequency and I want to convert output of flow sensor in to voltage.
I have searched in Google I have got some circuit.

http://www.circuitstoday.com/frequency-to-voltage-converter-using-lm331

when I am using that I am getting only 0.2v /0.3v max.

I have used exact components for these circuits which is mentioned on above link

If you one have experienced in this frequency to voltage converter circuit please share your knowledge to me

Comment: WHICH of the 5 million, 3 hundred, and 79 schematics that search turns up did you actually build?  You are aware that that sensor provides pulses at low frequencies (like, under 100Hz) and that most of the circuits you found are intended for much higher frequencies?

Comment: Sorry .kindly find the link on below

Comment: http://www.circuitstoday.com/frequency-to-voltage-converter-using-lm331

Comment: The link tells you how to calculate the expected voltage for a given frequency.  Have you tried calculating the voltage for pulse rate at your expected flow rate?  Maybe you should be getting a voltage of 0.2V.

Comment: No I was not calculated.i have directly given output of the sensor to this circuit.when I was measuring voltage at output side it's showing 0.2 to 0.3 v only.

Comment: For 100Hz, I get below 0.1 Volts.  That's a flow rate of more than 10 liters per minute according to the datasheet.  You might do better to count the number of pulses per second and calculate the flow rate from that.  Any small processor should be capable of the counting and calculating.

Comment: You should do the calculations for your expected flow rate.  Your measured value may be correct.  How did you plan to measure the flow rate without knowing what voltage to expect for a given flow rate?

Comment: http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/yf-s201-water-flow-meter.                                  The above link they were given pulse per liter is 450.up to 30ltr/min. They were given

Comment: Yeah. And what voltage can you expect from the f to v converter for that pulse range?  What flow rate are you trying to measure?  How fast is the water really flowing in your pipe?

Comment: I am expecting voltage 5v. App 10-15ltr per min is flowing through my pipe

Comment: Why do you expect 5V?  If you do the calculations using the formula given at the link you will find that the voltage should be quite low.  10 liters per minute is a pulse rate of 82 Hz.  82Hz will give a voltage way under 0.1V, which you would know and expect if you had done the calculations.

Comment: Could you share your calculation to me with example.you have used this formula  Vout = ((R4)/(R5+R6))*R1C1*2.09V*Fin. or another formula..

Comment: I used the one from the web site you linked to, which appears to be the one you just posted.

Comment: I used the full 5k for variable resistor R6.

Comment: My output 0.1 to 0.2v is correct right..I am going on the right way

Comment: Now, you can use that same equation to modify the LM331 circuit to provide a higher voltage at your low pulse rates.  Solve for C1, for example.  Then put in values for the voltage you want and the pulse rate you want that voltage to represent.  Now, you can calculate a value for C1 which will provide that voltage at that pulse rate.  Look up the datasheet for the LM331.  I'm sure you'lll find more guidance on designing the circuit you need.

Comment: Now that you know your voltage is as expected, go ahead and formulate it as answer, then accept that answer so this question will be marked as complete.  Explain what you were trying to do, and how you calculated the voltage to expect, and that what you measured was actually correct.  Include the circuit diagram, the values used, and the calculation.  All of that will help the next person who needs to use an LM331 and finds your question and answer.

Comment: Maybe even include a section on how you recalculated things to get the voltage you wanted for a particular pulse rate.